# Using Windows Phone dialer and Narrator

Tags: windows

Is there any way to make a call using the windows phone dialer in such a way that the person at the other end on answering the call can hear the text read out by Windows narrator. I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Cool idea for an new app. But does not exist yet :-) Perhaps if I have time I can do something for you.